# U2U caml query only brings back 30 rows

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I am currently trying to use U2U caml query builder to search through a sharepoint list, and although there are 400 records, regardless of the filters I use the result only brings back 30 rows even though there should be a lot more. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you building and running the query? 30 is standard item limit in the default list views, so it's probably something to do with that.